# How to speed up solr DIH with subqueries

Tags: mysql, solr, dih

I would like to speed up the DIH for a solr configuration that has the following structure:

- user entity (mapped to user table)
- user entity has 1..n values mapped to field of the user entity. so n additional fields
- every field is gathered through a subquery on value table.

example:

entity:user `(select * from user)`

user has the following fields:

```
value_1: (select * from value where uid=user.id and category=1)
value_2: (select * from value where uid=user.id and category=2)
value_3: (select * from value where uid=user.id and category=3)
```

As there is many subqueries, import takes too long.

whats the best approach to this using SOLR and DIH (MySQL) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can speed things up using SortedMapBachedCache

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-EntityProcessors

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this exact same issue, and at heart the problem is that neither MySQL nor Solr's SQL DIH has the built-in capacity to use a field *value* to help *name* a MySQL result column or a Solr field.

Ideally, you could do something like this: **THIS DOESN'T WORK!**

```xml
<entity name="value" query="select myfield, category from t1 where uid=${user.id}">
    <field column="myfield" name="value_${value.category}">
</entity>
```

Without this wonderful, non-existent feature, there are several ways to get similar functionality with less convenience.

[This page](http://kmt-studio.pl/programming/2014/04/25/tips-on-using-dih-with-solr/) shows a great analysis of two different methods for creating this functionality, either with the [ScriptTransformer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-TheScriptTransformer) (he found it simple to implement but it slowed down the import badly), or the [TemplateTransformer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-TheTemplateTransformer) (which requires you to compile a very short Java snippet, but is apparently *much* more efficient.

Again, [this](http://kmt-studio.pl/programming/2014/04/25/tips-on-using-dih-with-solr/) is likely the solution you want.

In my own case, I hadn't found this solution, and instead wrote a short Java program to make the SQL requests, build the SolrInputDocument and then submit them in batches to Solr. And then later the whole thing was made irrelevant when we decided to put all of the values into Solr as a single JSON-encoded field.

Good luck!